# Strftime with German Date

Tags: php, strftime

im trying to print the date in german with strftime. I already tried

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE", "de_DE@euro", "deu", "deu_deu", "german");
$time = strftime("%B", 1323956220);
echo $time;  //I want to see "Dezember", but I see "December" instead
```

but it didnt work. Am I missing something?

Edit: sorry I missed the strftime funciton :P

Comment: Can you show your entire code?

Comment: Please post an exact example of how you want the date to be displayed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the strftime function, duh :P

Comment: it seems to be work, could it be somewhere in your code that reset the locale?

Comment: Check what your preferred locale is: `$loc_de = setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE@euro", "de_DE", "de", "ge", "german"); echo "Locale: $loc_de";`

Comment: @luastoned No, you have to check which locales are available on the machine. See my answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess: the locale is actually called `de_DE.utf8` on your machine (it is on mine). Does this work for you?

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8"); // or LC_TIME
echo strftime('%B', 1323956220);
```

BTW: on Linux you can use `locale -a` to see what's available.

Comment: Worked flawlessly! So simple! Thanks! :)

Comment: +1 for `locale -a` (even if it's obvious ... I forgot to check on server)

Comment: Yes you need the `.utf8` on the end. I was just using `de_DE` and I could get "Januar" in my `strftime`-formatted dates but not "März".

Answer (score -1):

You'll need the Internationalization extension installed, but I recommend using the [IntlDateFormatter class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

Have a look at the manual first, but a quick example might look like this:

```
$fmt = datefmt_create("de_DE", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Berlin', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
echo datefmt_format($fmt , time());
```

Which outputs this:

**Donnerstag, 15. Dezember 2011**