# Translating PHP weekdays and months

Tags: php, date, for-loop, momentjs

Any ideas for translating PHP weekdays and months to local language? I have script which prints weekdays of next 5 weeks and I want that they are in other language.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('next Monday');
for ($i = 0; $i < 35; $i++) {
    echo strftime('%A', $timestamp)." ";
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
```

Is there any good integrations e.g. with PHP and moment.js? I have looked at [Use PHP's date() formats in moment.js](https://gist.github.com/NTICompass/9375143)  and [GitHub fightbulc/moment.php](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php)
, but I don't understand how to use those..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try google translate api. https://cloud.google.com/translate/

Comment: PHP already provides support for formatting dates in different languages. I see you already found out [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). It works together with [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). The PHP documentation of both functions provides usage examples.

Comment: @axiac, I added `setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");` but it doesn't have any effect. Weekdays keep showing in english.

Comment: The value to pass as the second argument to `setlocale()` depends on the OS where the PHP interpreter runs. Windows uses different naming rules. Also, sometimes the locale information is not installed for all languages. On Unix-like systems it usually can be installed.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8521388/4265352). Its [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521517/4265352) provides information about how to find out what value to use as the second argument of [`setlocale()`]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably looking for the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

**UPDATE**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi");
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%A'));
```

**RESULT**

```
perjantaina
```

And this as a gift for you guys - [the ISO language codes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)

Comment: I tried to add `setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");` before `strftime()` but it doesn't have any effect. Weekdays are in english.

Comment: @lingo see the update it give's you the result you need

Answer (score 9):

You coud use [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php), as follows:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('fin', IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
              IntlDateFormatter::NONE, null, null, "cccc"); 
$timestamp = strtotime('next Monday');
echo $fmt->format($timestamp);
```

Output:

> maanantai

Depending on the grammatical context you may need "eeee" as last argument instead of "cccc":

> maanantaina

Answer (score 3):

I made the following for really translating months and weekdays *from and to any language* (that is installed on the server).

Even thought this topic has long be answered, I will post it since it might really help some people.

setlocale() is used, but also reset; so it can't mess up the rest of your code.

These are the functions you can use:

`weekdayToEnglish($locale,$weekday,$short)`
`weekdayFromEnglish($locale,$weekday,$short)`
`monthToEnglish( $locale,$month,$short)`
`monthFromEnglish($locale,$month,$short)`

**$locale** is the language as you would use in [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), depends on your server, mostly something like 'fr_FR';

**$weekday** or **$month** the name of the weekday of month to be translated

(optional) **$short** if true gives (localized) short notation (like Thu in stead of Thursday or Oct instead of Octobre)

The code:

```
function weekdayToEnglish($locale,$weekday,$short=false) {
    return dateElementToEnglish($locale, $weekday, $short ? "%a" : "%A",
                                $short? "D" : "l", 'tm_wday', "Sunday +" ," days") ;
}

function weekdayFromEnglish($locale,$weekday,$short=false) {
    return dateElementFromEnglish($locale, $weekday, $short?"%a":"%A");
}

function monthToEnglish( $locale,$month,$short=false) {
    return dateElementToEnglish($locale, $month, $short ? "%b" : "%B",
                                $short ? "M" : "F", 'tm_mon', "January+" ," months") ;
}

function monthFromEnglish($locale,$month,$short=false) {
    return dateElementFromEnglish($locale, $month, $short ? "%b" : "%B");
}

function dateElementToEnglish($locale, $text, $strfTimeformat, $dateFormat,
                              $dateArrayIndex, $strToTimePrefix, $strToTimeSuffix) {
    $saveLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME,0);setlocale(LC_TIME,$locale);
    $translateToNr = strptime($text, $strfTimeformat)[$dateArrayIndex] ;
    $readDate = strtotime($strToTimePrefix . $translateToNr . $strToTimeSuffix);
    $translation = date($dateFormat, $readDate);
    setlocale(LC_TIME,$saveLocale);
    return $translation;
}

function dateElementFromEnglish($locale,$text,$strfTimeformat) {
    $saveLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME,0);setlocale(LC_TIME,$locale);
    $translation = strftime($strfTimeformat,strtotime($text));
    setlocale(LC_TIME,$saveLocale);
    return $translation;
}
```

For instance:

```
echo weekdayToEnglish("nl_NL","vrijdag")."<br>";
echo weekdayFromEnglish("fi_FI","Monday")."<br>";
echo weekdayToEnglish("nl_NL","wo", true)."<br>";
echo weekdayFromEnglish("de_DE","Thu", true)."<br>";
echo weekdayFromEnglish("fr_FR",weekdayToEnglish("nl_NL","zaterdag"))."<br>";
echo monthFromEnglish("de_DE", "March")."<br>";
echo monthFromEnglish("fr_FR", "February", true)."<br>";
echo monthToEnglish("fr_FR", "avril")."<br>";
echo monthToEnglish("fi_FI", "joulukuu", true)."<br>";
```

Will yield:

```
Friday
maanantai
Wed
Do
samedi
März
févr.
April
Dec
```

Comment: Always returns Thursday (i checked it on a saturday) when use `echo weekdayToEnglish("nl_NL","vrijdag")."<br>";`

Comment: That will be the case on some servers, I highly suspect because the particular language(s) is/are not installed on that server. If they are, it works fine, just tested it again.

Comment: See also
https://www.binarytides.com/php-get-list-of-locales-installed-on-system/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect